# Transform data to a new structure

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-access

I've got an Access database from one of our clients and want to import this data into a new MSSQL Server 2008 database structure I designed. It's similar to the Access Database (including all the columns and so on) but I normalized the entire database.

Is there any tool (microsoft tools preferred) to map the old database to my new design?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at using SSIS (part of SQL Server) which is a comprehensive set of tools for doing ETL.

Answer (score 2):

The current tool of choice is [SQL Server Migration Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=5abe098d-c7e1-46c6-994a-09a2856eef0b) (for the appropriate source database, i.e., comes in Access, Oracle, etc. flavors). But it replicates your Access database structure from scratch, rather than importing the data into your pre-built database.

Answer (score 0):

Built into Access is the SQL Upsize Wizard. You can use that - read up on it for all the details, but you should be good.

Comment: SSMA is signifcantly better than the SQL Upsizing Wizard built into Access.

Comment: A few days ago I posted my observations on using SSMA (http://www.accessmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/databases-ms-access/44398/SSMA-for-Access-4-2-Observations -- it's not on Google Groups for some reason), and today discovered it failed to upsize one of the relationships, even thought that relationship was present in the source database. So, you need to check the results REALLY CAREFULLY.